# Implement Motion Blur Filter Using EmguCv

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I want to implement Motion Blur Filter in C# using Emgu CV, what is the correct way to do this in fourier domain. I am currently stuck at how to perform multiply of Motion Blur filter and my Complex Fourier Image.